# How to search within an array in Java

Tags: java

I am making a simple java application that asks user for the subject they want tutors for, and then prints the tutors teaching that subject.

This is what I've written so far.

package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the subject: ");
    String tutorNeeded = userInput.nextLine();
    String[] theTutors = {"Phillip Banks: Mathematics", "William Smith: Physics", "Alex Ferguson: Computer Science", "Edwin Valero: Mathematics"};
    if (tutorNeeded.contains("Math")) {
        System.out.println("The tutor(s) for the following subject are: " + "\n" + theTutors[0] + "\n" + theTutors[3]);
    }else if (tutorNeeded.contains("Physics")) {
        System.out.println("The tutor(s) for the following subject are: " + "\n" + theTutors[1]);
    } else if (tutorNeeded.contains(("Computer"))) {
        System.out.println("The tutor(s) for the following subject are: " + "\n" + theTutors[2]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, we don't have any tutors for that subject availible right now.");
    }
}
```

}

This code works, but I was wondering what If I had to enter a lot of new information. This would be too time consuming, as I would have to enter the new tutor in the main array and also the print statement. How do I make this more efficient?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Could you show your attempts? Are you stuck somewhere in your code? Please update your question accordingly (see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: It is important that you show what you have done and where you are having issues. That is the essence of Stack Overflow

Comment: You search an array by looking at different elements of the array  until you find the one you're looking for.  Without more detail about the specific  problem at hand, it's hard to say more than that.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys! I'll edit my main question

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, you would have to iterate over the array. Something in the same spirit as this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the subject: ");
    String tutorNeeded = userInput.nextLine();
    String[] theTutors = {"Phillip Banks: Mathematics", "William Smith: Physics", "Alex Ferguson: Computer Science", "Edwin Valero: Mathematics"};
    String foundTutors = "";
    for (String tutor: theTutors) {
        if(tutor.contains(tutorNeeded){
            foundTutors = "\n" + tutor;
        }
    }
    if (foundTutors.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, we don't have any tutors for that subject availible right now.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The tutor(s) for the following subject are:" + foundTutors);
    }
}
```

Another idea would be to save a Map, mapping all subjects to a list of teachers. Then you could easily extend this. Or creating a Teacher class, which has a subject, which he teaches, and then saving a list of teachers. There a many, many ways how to implement something like this